# Comparing numbers in different rows

Tags: python, csv

I'm working on a final for my Python class and I'm comparing two files by comparing each month's data with the next month's data over the course of 10 years. For example, if January 2010's data is 3215.67 and the following February 2010's data is 3673.12, I want to compare those two numbers and then find the % change between them. Such as if I was simply dividing one by the other with a calculator. But then after finding the % change of January 2010 and February 2010, I'd like my program to then compare February 2010 with March 2010. I'm more than sure that a for loop would be needed but I'm not exactly sure how to set it up so I'd like an explanation or an example of how to go about doing it.

If I need to give more information or go as far as giving out the entirety of my project with its data files and program I have so far, (which I don't really intend on doing unless I get really desperate because I'd prefer to learn how to do it rather than having someone else just do my final for me) please reply asking so. Thank you in advance.

Comment: First off without knowing how your data is stored somebody is unlikely to be able to help you. Secondly what have you tried so far show some code!
Your controlflow should be something like  `get first file > read Data > get second file > read data > compare data > get next file ...`

Comment: The data I'm using are csv files from Yahoo! Finance specifically NASDAQ Composite and S&P 500. Most of the values there are floats with the date being a string due to it being in the format (Year-Month-Date) with the hyphens. So far what I've done with my coding is writing the variables but I'm stuck on trying to get the float data into a loop which would perform the comparisons that I want. My control flow is  the same as what you mentioned but now I'm trying to find the % difference between each month and then I would have to compare that with the same pair of months of the second file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could either construct a dictionary, put all your data in there and using a for loop iterate though it, or do smth straightforward like the following:

```
import glob
files = glob.glob(yourpath + '/*.extension')
resultList = []
for filename in files:
    with open(filename,'r') as f:
        newData = int([x.strip() for x in f.readlines()][0])
    try:
        resultList.append(newData/oldData)
    except:
        pass
    oldData = newData
print(resultList)
```